# Matching a JS string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long xml raw message that is being stored in a string format. A sample is as below.

```
 <tag1>val</tag><tag2>val</tag2><tagSomeNameXYZ/>
```

I'm looking to search this string and find out if it contains an empty html tag such as `<tagSomeNameXYZ/>`. This thing is, the value of *SomeName* can change depending on context. I've tried using    `Str.match(/tagSomeNameXYZ/g)` and `Str.match(/<tag.*.XYZ\/>/g)` to find out if it contains exactly that string, but am able to get it return anything. I'm having trouble in writing a reg ex that matches something like `<tag*XYZ/>`, where `*` is going to be `SomeName` (which I'm not interested in)

Tl;dr : How do I filter out `<tagSomeNameXYZ/>` from the string. Format being : `<constant  variableName constant/>`

Example patterns that it should match:

```
<tagGetIndexXYZ/>
<tagGetAllIndexXYZ/>
<tagGetFooterXYZ/>
```

Comment: Don't parse XML with regexp. Parse it and walk the DOM, or use XPath with `document.evaluate` to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have with `Str.match(/<tag.*.XYZ\/>/g)` is the .* takes everything it sees and does not stop at the XYZ as you wish. So you need to find a way to stop (e.g. the `[^/]*` means keep taking until you find a `/`) and then work back from there (the `slice`).

Does this help

```js
testString = "<tagGetIndexXYZ/>"
res = testString.match(/<tag([^/]*)\/\>/)[1].slice(0,-3)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this. Could you please explain briefly what it does? Specifically the slice part.

Comment: That removes the XYZ at the end. If your constant at the end were different you would need to change -3 to something else

Comment: Would the person that down voted please provide a better solution so that we can all learn?

Comment: The question was to eliminate these self-closed tags from the input, not how to find the *SomeName* of the first one.